# Can XPath be used to search a <script> block?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, xpath, selector

I'm OK skills-wise at selecting all sorts of HTML content. So all confident creating some code that should be ripping content of a site I stumbled across some strange JavaScript code where the source puts its prices in.

```
<script>
 var productConfig = {"attributes":{"178":{"id":"178","code":"bp_flavour","label":"Smaak","options":[{"id":"28","label":"Aardbeien","oldPrice":"0","products":["2292","2294","2296","2702"]}
```

.... more gibberish and than 4 of each product variation: (so like 80 different lines like this:)

```
,"childProducts":{
"2292":"price":"64.99","finalPrice":"64.99","no_of_servings":"166","178":"27","179":"34"},
"2292":"price":"17.99","finalPrice":"17.99","no_of_servings":"33","178":"28","179":"25"}
}


</script>
```

Apparently 2292 is the id of the product at hand. I would like to read out the "finalPrice".

My PHP code:

```
    $file = $this->curl_get_file_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
   @$doc->loadHTML($file);
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);

    $price_query = $finder->query("//script[contains(.,'finalPrice')]");
    $price_raw = $price_query->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

However my query `//script[contains(.,"finalPrice")]` blasts out the whole script I cant find a way to dig deeper and more specifically in the JavaScript. Does anyone know more/could give me a hint?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hey i edited it to be more specific

Comment: The expression on the right side of `=` looks like JSON so parsing it using http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php might be the bettter option than using regular expressions.

Comment: Definitely. Assuming it's JSON, then read it as a string using XPath, and then put it into a JSON parser.

Comment: Json decode was the master in here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did: read out the script with the provided XPATH query. Than: strstr till i got the json parts I wanted. Next up was: PHP's json_decode function. Puts it in an array than searched the arrays for what i wanted. This is my code for the parsing:

```
        $price_query = $finder->query("//script[contains(.,'finalPrice')]");
        $price_raw = $price_query->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $price_1 = strstr($price_raw, "childProducts");
        $price_2 = str_replace('childProducts":', '', $price_1);
        $price_3 = strstr($price_2, ',"priceFromLabel"', true);     
        $price_data = json_decode($price_3, true);
```

Looks like crap with the str str but works. Thanks all for your thoughts. json_decode ftw!

Answer (score 0):

You may try regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("/finalPrice\\":\\"([0-9.]{1,10})\\"/", $page_html, $output_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer how would i modify this snippet to select only the finalprices where the "ID" is 2292? Like this? preg_match_all("/2292\\":"/finalPrice\\":\\"([0-9.]{1,10})\\"/", $page_html, $output_array);

Comment: Check this out:
preg_match_all("/2292(.*)finalPrice\\":\\"([0-9.]{1,10})\\"/", $input_lines, $output_array);

Answer (score 0):

You can read properties from object like this.

```
var obj = {"2292":{"price":"64.99","finalPrice":"64.99","no_of_servings":"166","178":"27","179":"34"}};
obj['2292']['finalPrice']
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I modified the javascript in my question to be more specific. The object name = productConfig, the variable in which i search is childProducts. Inside that var is an array which contains the 2292 product (4 times) i tried this as my query: 

productConfig['childProducts']['2290']['finalPrice'])

It did not return anything. Do you know what im doing wrong here?