# Get string data Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, get, gecko, geckofx

I need help to get data from the site. I use geckofx in my application. I want it to retrieve text data from the xpath location after loading the page

```
XPathResult xpathResult = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.EvaluateXPath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]");
IEnumerable<GeckoNode> foundNodes = xpathResult.GetNodes();
```

How to download data as text?

Comment: Do you want the elements inner or outter HTML? Have you tried any code yet? Do you want to download it to some location or just to use the output on your code?

Comment: this is an external website. I want to save the text of this location later, for example in excel

Comment: I don't really know if your problem is on getting the correct nodes or saving it to a file or if you want the elements inner or outter HTML.

Try providing more information, and you'll probably have better chances to get an answer.

Is the code you posted correct? Do you have any error outputs? What is the expected result? Have you tried anything else?

Comment: foundNodes is not a string value. I do not know how to convert it. Maybe you know another method to get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are struggling to retrieve the text from the GeckoFX objects.
Here are a few calls and operations that should get you started:

```
//get by XPath
XPathResult xpathResult = _browser.Document.EvaluateXPath("//*[@id]/div/p[2]");
var foundNodes = xpathResult.GetNodes();
foreach (var node in foundNodes)
{
    var x = node.TextContent; // get text text contained by this node (including children)
    GeckoHtmlElement element = node as GeckoHtmlElement; //cast to access.. inner/outerHtml
    string inner = element.InnerHtml;
    string outer = element.OuterHtml;
    //iterate child nodes
    foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
    {

    }
}
//get by id
GeckoHtmlElement htmlElementById = _browser.Document.GetHtmlElementById("mw-content-text");
//get by tag
GeckoElementCollection byTag = _browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (var ele in byTag)
{
    var y = ele.GetAttribute("value");

}
//get by class
var byClass = _browser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("input");
foreach (var node in byClass)
{
    //...
}

//cast to a different object
var username = ((GeckoInputElement)_browser.Document.GetHtmlElementById("yourUsername")).Value;
//create new object from DomObject
var button = new GeckoButtonElement(_browser.Document.GetElementById("myBtn").DomObject);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That's what it was! I have already started using the WebAutomation code where there is a lot of confusion. Your code is shorter and it works properly. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have one more question. I would like to extract from the script the value of the "code" variable, how to do it? xpath /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/script
 function test
 {
   //
   // 
   
  {
   //
   var code = "f6738a09443b6a54b26cd6f4c7f2c4a9";
   //
   
  }
 }

Comment: @DonCorleone AFAIK you can not query the content of a script tag like HTML. However, you can extract the text of the script tag and search the JavaScript code using regex or similar, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718783/can-xpath-be-used-to-search-a-script-block  but that's another question..

Answer (score 0):

```
public string extract(string xpath, string type)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        GeckoHtmlElement elm = null;

        GeckoWebBrowser wb = geckoWebBrowser1;//(GeckoWebBrowser)GetCurrentWB();
        if (wb != null)
        {
            elm = GetElement(wb, xpath);
            if (elm != null)
                //UpdateUrlAbsolute(wb.Document, elm);

            if (elm != null)
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case "html":
                        result = elm.OuterHtml;
                        break;
                    case "text":
                        if (elm.GetType().Name == "GeckoTextAreaElement")
                        {
                            result = ((GeckoTextAreaElement)elm).Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = elm.TextContent.Trim();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "value":
                        result = ((GeckoInputElement)elm).Value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = extractData(elm, type);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    private string extractData(GeckoHtmlElement ele, string attribute)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        if (ele != null)
        {
            var tmp = ele.GetAttribute(attribute);
            /*if (tmp == null)
            {
                tmp = extractData(ele.Parent, attribute);
            }*/
            if (tmp != null)
                result = tmp.Trim();
        }

        return result;
    }
    private object GetCurrentWB()
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            if(tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count > 0)
            //if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                Control ctr = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];

                if (ctr != null)
                {

                    return ctr as object;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private GeckoHtmlElement GetElement(GeckoWebBrowser wb, string xpath)
    {
        GeckoHtmlElement elm = null;
        if (xpath.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            if (xpath.Contains("@class") || xpath.Contains("@data-type"))
            {
                var html = GetHtmlFromGeckoDocument(wb.Document);
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);

                var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
                if (node != null)
                {
                    var currentXpath = "/" + node.XPath;
                    elm = (GeckoHtmlElement)wb.Document.EvaluateXPath(currentXpath).GetNodes().FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                elm = (GeckoHtmlElement)wb.Document.EvaluateXPath(xpath).GetNodes().FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            elm = (GeckoHtmlElement)wb.Document.GetElementById(xpath);
        }
        return elm;
    }
    private string GetHtmlFromGeckoDocument(GeckoDocument doc)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        GeckoHtmlElement element = null;
        var geckoDomElement = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
        {
            element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;
            result = element.InnerHtml;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = extract("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[2]", "text");
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
```

I also insert the code from which I used a little longer code but it also works. maybe someone will need it. The creator of the code is Đinh Công Thắng, Web Automation App,
Regards